# Javascript - Pop up box running off timer

Tags: javascript

I'm extremely new to Javascript and would like to create a simple pop up box that displays at a specific time when the counter is running (i.e. When the counter has 10 minutes to go, display text)

I've taken this snippet of code from W3 ...

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
demo {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("{case_started}").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

     // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

}, 1000);


</script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming that this is super easy and I apologise in advance, i've scoured the web ....

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `{case_started}` on `new Date()` ?

Comment: I think its supposed to be replaced by PHP or server-side templating language to the start date.

Comment: {case_started} is an internal system's case start timer. I replaced 'wednesday 4th May etc ...' with {case_started}. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script misses an end bracket `}`.

I edited your script:

**In this code sample I edited the date function to work, because the variable `{case_started}` is not working.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
demo {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("2018/03/06").getTime(); //replaced {case_started} by a hardcoded date

// Store if 10 minute alert is already showed
var alert_shown = false;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If 10 minutes or less
    if (distance < 600000 && !alert_shown) {
      alert_shown = true;
      alert("Less than 10 minutes to go!");
    }

     // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    } //added missing end bracket

}, 1000);


</script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your speedy response!It's now counting up, thanks - However, I need to include a modal type pop up (it doesn't have to be modal, just a standard pop up if it's easier) to appear when the timer hits 10 minutes, for example and i'm struggling ....

Comment: You mean an `alert()` or in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Yes, an alert in JS

Comment: It didn't work - Thanks for editing and responding though. I wonder if it's because of the internal platform that i'm trying to use it in.

Comment: @Jake It does work in my answer. So please accept my answer, and if you got a different problem look it up or post it again on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's more than likely because the internal system that i'm using doesn't respond well to Javascript. iI'm not saying it didn't work. I'm saying that it doesn't work in my internal platform. Thank you for your responses and time :)

Comment: @Jake If the particular question you've asked is solved by my answer then please mark it anyways. If it is not working in your internal system that should be mentioned in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I've added days and hours, but you can remove it if you want.

You had a little typo in your code, a missing `}` for the `if (distance < 0) {` condition.

Also, your css selector has to be `#demo`, instead of `demo`.

I've replaced `{case_started}` with a real date so the example works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#demo {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("2018/03/07 17:30:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Calculate days, hours minutes and seconds left
    var seconds = (countDownDate - now) / 1000;
    var days = parseInt(seconds / 86400);

    seconds = seconds % 86400;
    hours = parseInt(seconds / 3600);
    seconds = seconds % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds % 60);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }

}, 1000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```